# How to simulate AR(p) model with trend

Tags: time-series, simulation, autoregressive, trend

### Backgrounds

I have a time series, and I fitted an AR(p) model with trend of $t^2$, with the help of `auto.arima`, in `R` package `forecast`.

```
result = auto.arima(X, max.order=10, stepwise=F, max.d=0, max.q=0, xreg=I(t^2))
```

And I got AR(3) model, and I inspected the fitted coefficients as follows:

```
## z test of coefficients:
##
## Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
## ar1  some_number - ***
## ar2  some_number - ***
## ar3  some_number - ***
## intercept  some_number - ***
## xreg  some_number - ***
```

which clearly tells me the results of $\hat{\phi_1}, \hat{\phi_2}, \hat{\phi_3}$, and the intercept, $\hat{\mu}$, and the coefficient of $t^2$ term, say $\hat{\beta_{t^2}}$.

---

### Problem

I would like to simulate from the model fitted above, with $\hat{\phi_1}, \hat{\phi_2}, \hat{\phi_3}, \hat{\mu}, \hat{\beta_{t^2}}$.

$$
(X_t - \hat{\mu}) = \hat{\phi_1} X_{t-1} + \hat{\phi_2} X_{t-2} + \hat{\phi_3} X_{t-3} + \hat{\beta_{t^2}} t^2
$$

But I'm stuck at how I should proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the initial values $X_1,X_2,X_3$ (they are set to zero in the code below) and then draw a vector of shocks $\epsilon_4,...,\epsilon_T$. You can then calculate $X_4,...,X_T$ using a loop. For drawing the shocks, you either can assume shocks are normally distributed and draw from $N(0,\hat{\sigma}_{\epsilon}^2)$ or sample with replacement from the residual vector. The code will look something like this:

```
    #--You need to set the values of T,mu,phi1,phi2,phi3,beta,sigmahat--#
x<-rep(0,T)
epsilon<-rnorm(T, mean = 0, sd = sigmahat)
for (t in 4:T) {
x[t]<-mu+phi1*x[t-1]+phi2*x[t-2]+phi3*x[t-3]+beta*t^2+epsilon[t]
}
```